# ..., on the other hand,

Tags: singular-vs-plural, case

Is it a correct way to say

> **Me**, on the other hand, **was/were** feeling increasingly uneasy.

Are highlighted words used here correctly?

Comment: I was feeling uneasy. *on the other hand* is just a supplement and has no influence on the main clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Me* is objective; if you use it instead of *I*, the clause lacks a subject. The *on the other hand* is a parenthetical element and does not change the pronoun nor the corresponding conjugation.

> **I** ***was*** feeling uneasy.
>
> **I**, on the other hand, ***was*** feeling uneasy.